# Which of these data models is the most correct?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm in the process of creating the data model for an application I will be developing, and I was hoping to get some feedback on part of the model. The app will be a complete redevelopment of something that was created in Lotus Notes, and one of the main purposes of the redevelopment is to move toward a relational data storage layer.

The application is focused on managing `Things`. The requirements/constraints of the application are:

1. A `Thing` must have an associated `Location`.
2. A `Location` could be for example 'McDonalds', or 'Melbourne Uni, Building AK, Room 301' where 'Melbourne Uni', 'Building AK', and 'Room 301' are seperate related `Locations`.
3. (at least) 3 levels/tiers of `Location` must exist
4. There must be a provision for 'Other' locations, so that users can enter free text for a location that does not exist in the database

So I've come up with 4 different implementations of the above, but I don't really have enough DBA experience to know which one is the most correct.

[Location / Thing relational model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVqM5.jpg)

Any thoughts and/or suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using nested sets for putting things into locations?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model  Just a different way of modeling parent/child relationships that is easier to query/maintain.

Comment: @ryan1234 I hadn't heard of the nested set model before, thanks for the link. It seems like overkill though for a tree that's probably only going to be 3 levels deep.

Comment: Yeah definitely not useful for something that would have max 3 levels.

Comment: You should also consider other hierarchical models like the Adjacency List, the Path Enumeration and the Closure model (or combination). A small introductional slideshow: **[Models for hierarchical data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)** (It focuses on MySQL and mainly on Closure model but it has good comparison between models and advantages/disdvantages). Of course the choice of DBMS should matter as well.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube, that's a pretty nice summary of options. Looks like my options 2's are similar to the closure model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both option 1s are likely to prove inflexible and difficult to amend if your estimate of three levels proves to be insufficient.

In your option 2s, the entity that looks dubious is ThingOtherLocations. Anything that (from its name) is concatenating two different concepts is automatically suspect.If it is the case that you do have two separate concepts here, then the structure of option 2b does not need either OtherLocation or ThingOtherLocation. I suspect that the relation you are trying to represent (gets its name from) is actually another relation between locations - though I am not clear on this.

**EDIT**

In the light of your clarification of the ThingOtherLocations, I would suggest that you treat the text associated with Other simply as a new location, and store the new location along with other locations. There does not seem to be any reason to include special database handling for these cases.

**EDIT**

To deal with the child location issue, you might like to consider Joe Celko's work on nested sets. The primary reference for this is:

```
Joe Celko.     
Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties, 
(The Morgan Kaufmann Series in Data Management Systems)
ISBN 1-55860-920-2
```

Comment: I probably didn't explain the "other location" part well enough. Basically at any level in the location hierarchy the user may be able to select "Other" as the location. If "Other" is selected then they will have to specify the location as text. `ThingOtherLocation` is trying to capture that for 1 "other" entry in the hierarchy there will be different user text, and it is specific to a `Thing`

Comment: I think your point of treating 'other' locations as new locations is probably the right way to go, otherwise there is likely to be a lot of data duplication.